# How do I pass a variable to a form from a link

Tags: javascript, html, css, jinja2

I am trying to pass the sets ID to a form when a user clicks on the link. Semantic is being used for the frontend.

When the user is viewing a Class, they see a button that says 'New Survey' as below:

[image: View class]

This is the HTML:

```
<a href="/form/create?set_dropdown={{set.id}}">
<button class="ui labeled icon button green">
<i class="inverted plus icon"></i>
    New Survey
</button>
</a>
```

This is the field that is being targeted:

```
<div class="ui selection dropdown" id="set_dropdown">
<input type="hidden" id='class_dropdown' name="set">
<i class="dropdown icon"></i>
<div class="default text">Class</div>
<div class="menu">
    {% for set in sets %}
    <div class="item" data-value="{{ set.id }}">{{ set.name }}</div>

    {% endfor %}

</div>
</input>
</div>
```

Its a dropdown that is dynamically rendered in with Jinja2.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can use `request.args` to retrieve parameter from the url

`{{ request.args.get('set_dropdown') }}`

use this and set a unique id for the selection drop down:

```
<div class="ui selection dropdown" id="set_dropdown_{{ request.args.get('set_dropdown') }}">
<input type="hidden" id='class_dropdown' name="set">
<i class="dropdown icon"></i>
<div class="default text">Class</div>
<div class="menu">
    {% for set in sets %}
    <div class="item" data-value="{{ set.id }}">{{ set.name }}</div>

    {% endfor %}

</div>
</input>
</div>
```